# IE9 Alert() now blocks range.select from displaying selected text

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, range, alert

I have a button on a page, that when pressed, searches thru data on the form, highlights a certain field, and javascript ALERT()'s the user of the found word.  Once the user OK's the ALERT(), the javascript searches and highlights the next occurence of the word, and realerts, and continues this behavior until no further data is found.

Prior to IE9, the below code worked fine to produce this behavior (this is a very simple version of the code, which demonstrates the problem).  Normally (prior to IE9) at the pause of the first ALERT(), the text is highlighted on the screen, but under IE9, it is not.  With IE9, nothing displays highlighted until after the entire script completes (after the second alert), and at that time only the last found string is highlighted.  This prevents the application from stepping thru and highlighting each found word and Alerting the user.

Try running the below under IE9, then under IE8 and below.  I don't need to worry in this situation about other browsers, just IE (it is a controlled browser application enviroment):

---

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form name="MYFORM">
<input type="text" value="NAME/JONES   ADDR/123 MAIN" name="myinput" size="40">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

   var range = document.MYFORM.myinput.createTextRange();

   var strFound=range.findText("NAME/");
   range.select();
   alert("Message 1");

   var strFound=range.findText("ADDR/");
   range.select();
   alert("Message 2");

</script>

</body>
```

Thanks for any insight into fixing the code to work under IE9.

Kevin

Comment: Have you checked the console during IE9 running it to see if there are any errors being thrown?

Comment: I'm afraid there is nothing you can do when you use a native alert. Is it an option to use something else, e.g. jQueryUI-dialog ?

Comment: Yes, I've checked the debugger, and no errors are thrown.  I've also tried using IE9 developer tools to set the Browser mode to 9, 8, 7 and compatibility mode, and it still exhibits the "bad" behavior.  But, running in native IE8 or 7, it works.  I don't have the option of using anything other than native Javascript.

Comment: Actually, the same "bad" behavior occurs whether you use a PROMPT() or an ALERT().  I'm actually using the PROMPT() in the real application, but both PROMPT and ALERT produce the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to give the UI time to repaint - do this by splitting your code into sections that can be scheduled using `setTimeout(nextIteration, 0);`.